# How does SSR working with high load?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, server-rendering

I'm currently designing a new web application and I would like to use next.js for SSR (with React, Redux, SCSS (CSS-Modules)).

1) Does anyone have an experience in using next.js on the projects with high load? 
2) And any benchmarks on after.js, razzle, next.js? 
3) React SSR framework vs Pug, Nunjucks, PHP?

P.S. I apologize if such questions have already been raised.

Comment: Did you get any answers to this ? There is only one throughput comparison https://malloc.fi/performance-cost-of-server-side-rendered-react-node-js